# AI Train/Test Split in Set Builder Notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, machine-learning

I'd like to express the splitting of input vectors and their corresponding labels in set builder notation. My question consists of a few smaller parts.

Consider a set of input vectors $X = \{\hat{x}_n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}, 0 \leq n \lt C \}$, where $C$ is the total number of available input vectors. It is often the case in AI problems that you wish to split the input set into two uneven parts $X_{\text{train}}$ and $X_{\text{test}}$. Let's assume an $80\%$ train, $20\%$ test scenario. So, my first question is how to best represent this. I have considered binomial coefficient notation followed by set subtraction:

$$
X_\text{test} \in {X \choose {\lfloor \frac{C}{5} \rfloor}} \qquad X_\text{train} = X \setminus X_\text{test}
$$

Is the above valid? This leads to the next question: for labels, lets say we have $y = \{\lambda_n \in \{0, 1\} \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}, 0 \leq n \lt C \}$. Is it enough to say:

$$
y_\text{test} = \{\lambda_n \mid \hat{x}_n \in X_\text{test}\} \qquad y_\text{train} = \{\lambda_n \mid \hat{x}_n \in X_\text{train}\}
$$

or do I need to qualify the possible values of $n$ again, or include a $\forall$ somewhere, or am I just generally way off in notation? If I am, would something like the union of sets notation work?

$$
y_\text{test}  = \bigcup_{x_n \in X_{\text{test}}} \{\lambda_n\} \qquad y_\text{train}  = \bigcup_{x_n \in X_{\text{train}}} \{\lambda_n\}
$$

Or does this just present the same issues as above?

Comment: Frankly speaking, the notation for $X_{\text {test}}$ is weird... Having defined $X$ in set-builder notation, it will be more clear to specify it as a subset of $X$: $X_{\text{test}} =\{ \hat{x}_n \mid \hat{x}_n \in X \text { and } \ldots \}$,

Comment: Regarding the $y$s, you can directly use $y_{\text{test}}= \{ λ_n \in \{ 0,1, \} \mid \hat{x}_n ∈X_{\text{test}} \}$. Maybe also here we need the "rule" connecting $ λ_n$ to $\hat{x}_n$...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA yeah, I agree it's a bit odd to use that notation, although I've struggled to come up with an alternative. Great point on the $y$s. No need to re-define $n$ I suppose. But yes, that rule... it feels strange for the subscript to be the "important part". Looking back at it with fresh eyes, it does make *decent* sense, but would probably cause a double-take when reading, and I'm worried about ambiguity.